# change color of single text attribute inside svg incase of multiple

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using a [gauge](https://github.com/recogizer/angular-gauge-chart) chart NPM package in my angular application and using a semi-circle gauge. I just want to change the color of the inner label. and this SVG is dynamic which is generated by the package in DOM

```
<rg-gauge-chart _ngcontent-yct-c10="" class="gauge-width fyf" _nghost-yct-c12="" ng-reflect-canvas-width="200" ng-reflect-needle-value="65" ng-reflect-central-label="1%" ng-reflect-options="[object Object]" style="fill: red;">
    <div _ngcontent-yct-c12="" class="gauge-chart" style="width: 200px;"><span _ngcontent-yct-c12="">  </span>
        <div _ngcontent-yct-c12="">
            <svg width="200" height="130">
                <text x="19.25" y="100.6" font-size="13px" font-family="Roboto,Helvetica Neue,sans-serif">24.2%</text>
                <text x="141.75" y="100.6" font-size="13px" font-family="Roboto,Helvetica Neue,sans-serif">24.0%</text>
                <text x="89.08" y="85" font-size="19.5px" font-family="Roboto,Helvetica Neue,sans-serif">1%</text>
            </svg>
        </div><span _ngcontent-yct-c12="" class="gauge-chart__label">  </span></div>
</rg-gauge-chart>
```

and this is the typescript code.

```
changeGaugeValueContent() {
    const svg = document.getElementsByClassName('fyf');
    for(let obj of svg) {
      obj.style.fill = 'red';
    }
  }
```

it works as expected and changes the color of all text values red. but what I want to achieve is I just want to change the color of the last text attribute in SVG.

Comment: `document.querySelector("svg > text:last-of-type").style.fill = "red"` should do the trick.

Comment: thanks man it works like a charm and I just modify your suggested solution as this will create problems in case of multiple SVG on the same page. `document.querySelector(".className svg > text:last-of-type").style.fill = "red"`